# Inspect all objects of all types in visual studio debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way , in VS 2013 debugger, to inspect all currently available objects in the process? (which haven't been disposed yet by the GC)

For example, at a certain point in the execution there are 3 instances of type A and 2 instances of type B. I'd like to pause the execution and inspect them all

Comment: I know of no built in tool to do this, but you can download a trial at http://memprofiler.com/ which will show you exactly what you want

Comment: It is possible, you'd use the `!dumpheap` command that's supported by the SOS debugger extension.  Used to work inside VS, today best used in Windbg.  But keep in mind that looking at the *entire* GC heap is never actually that useful, the information overload is almost always too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with debugging tools such as WinDBG - just save a process dump with VS, open WinDBG and type the following commands:

.symfix
.reload
.loadby sos clr
!dumpheap -stat

You can also archive similar functionality in VS by using some debugging plugins, such as Oz Code, by right clicking the type and showing all instances for each type - press the Show Instances of type button on the toolbar and just enter any substring of the types fully qualified name, like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When you are debugging your application, go to Debug > Windows > Autos (or press Ctrl+Alt+V, A)

You need to select the stack to see the variables' created in that call

[image: Stack Frame Dropdown]

Comment: This just shows all the instances in the current context of execution, not all the instances created by the process

Comment: It shows the latest stack's variables' context. If you would like to see the variables' context from a previous call (such as a recursive call / parent call), you should select the appropriate stack from the 'StackFrame' drop-down

Comment: And an object not in the current stack?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes - you can view it as long as you select the right stack. Please see my updated answer where I've attached a snapshot from VS 2013 IDE